# Thread-safe updates of a WinForm control from other classes

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, multithreading, thread-safety

Could someone please help me with the following problem:

There are two classes MainForm and LWriter.  Below is a method from the LWriter that in addition to writing to a file sends some updates to a RichTextBox control (through mainForm.UpdateLog(text)). Everything works fine, however, this WriteOutput method also does some extensive processing that during the calculation freezes the form.

I think the WriteOutput should be encapsulated in a separate thread. Could someone please help me out explaining how to place WriteOutput (LWriter class) in a thread that will then call mainForm.UpdateLog() from the mainFrom in a safe manner?

I am new to threads, thus help would be much appreciated.

```
public void WriteOutput(string output, Links[] links)
{
   try {
      using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(output)) {
         for (int x= 1; x<links.Length;x++) {
       ...
           sw.WriteLine( ... );
           sw.Flush();                              
         }
         mainForm.UpdateLog(<text>);
      }
   } catch(Exception e) { ... }
}
```

Comment: Why complicate it with threads? Anyway, one of the simplest ways to do something in the background in WinForms is to use the `BackgroundWorker` class. Within the `DoWork` method you'll need to guard any objects which might shared, as appropriate (and do *not* touch the UI). In the `DoWorkCompleted` event you can update the UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`delegate` can be used for Thread safe calls

Check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx

```
            // This delegate enables asynchronous calls for setting
    // the text property on a TextBox control.
    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

    // This method demonstrates a pattern for making thread-safe
    // calls on a Windows Forms control. 
    //
    // If the calling thread is different from the thread that
    // created the TextBox control, this method creates a
    // SetTextCallback and calls itself asynchronously using the
    // Invoke method.
    //
    // If the calling thread is the same as the thread that created
    // the TextBox control, the Text property is set directly. 

    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
        // If these threads are different, it returns true.
        if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {   
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Typically you should run this kind of time-consuming operations in a `BackgroundWorker`. Define a work method:

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{   
    // execute your WriteOutput method
}
```

and set is as the `DoWork` event handler:

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
worker.RunWorkerAsync(); // start the worker
```

To safely update the UI from a different thread use the `Control.BeginInvoke` method:

```
mainForm.BeginInvoke(
   () => { mainForm.UpdateLog(<text>); });
```

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by Sonu, `delegate` can be used for Thread safe calls, and you can use Linq to shorten the code:

```
this.BeginInvoke( (Action) delegate ()
{
       //code to update UI
});
```

See [this link](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2009/11/24/control-invoke-and-begininvoke-using-lamba-and-anonymous-delegates/) for more information.

Comment: By far the most elegant solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Interactions with UI controls **must** be done on the UI thread. You can build the string on a background thread, but you should use Control.Invoke or Control.BeginInvoke to marshal to the UI thread before interacting with it.

Lots of examples of this on the net and stack overflow.